# Cohomology of $T^{2} \times \mathbb{R}^{2}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology, exact-sequence, de-rham-cohomology

I need to find the cohomology groups $H^{k}_{dR}$ of $T^{2} \times \mathbb{R}^{2}$ (where by $T^{2}$ I mean the two-torus).

I would like to use the Mayer Vietoris sequence. Any advice on which open subsets $U$ and $V$ (whose union covers the manifold) I should choose?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you allowed to reduce the problem to calculating $H^*_{dR}(T^2)$ since $T^2$ and $T^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2$ are homotopy equivalent?

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, in fact $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is homotopy equivalent to the point and the cartesian product between the torus and the point is homotopy equivalent to the torus. How could I construct the maps to show that the Cartesian product between the torus and the point is homotopy equivalent to the point?

Comment: Well, $T^2 \times \{*\}$ is not homotopy equivalent to a point. But if you meant $T^2 \times \{*\}$ is homotopy equivalent to $T^2$, they're actually homeomorphic via the maps $(x, *) \mapsto x$ and $x \mapsto (x, *)$.

Comment: Yes, I meant the torus. Thank you very much